# When can a function $f(x_0 - x)$ be approximated as $f(x_0 - x) = f(x_0) - f'(x_0) x$?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, mathematics, approximations

When can a function $f(x_0 - x)$ be approximated as $f(x_0 - x) = f(x_0) - f'(x_0) x$? In Reif's statistical mechanics it is said that when $x$ is much smaller than $x_0$ then the approximation can be made. But if $x$ itself is a large number, then the $x^2, x^3, \cdots$ terms will also be important. Why then can we use this linear approximation?

For example, in deriving canonical distribution, $x_0$ is the total energy of the system A and the heat reservoir A'. $x$ is the energy of the system A which is much smaller than $x_0$. Then it is said that $\ln\Omega'(x_0-x)=\ln\Omega'(x_0)-(\partial\ln\Omega'/\partial x')_0 x$. Why?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic But it is the question I frequently encountered in studying statistical mechanics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically when we approximate functions via Taylor series in physics, it's **always** best practice to "non-dimensionalize" your functions first, and expand in a unitless variable. In this case, this would mean converting $f(x-x_0)$ to $f(1-x/x_0)$. That process may itself be nontrivial, but once it's done, the accuracy of the expansion becomes trivial to see.

If for some reason you can't or won't do that, then:

**We have to be very careful what we mean when we say that $x$ is much smaller than $x_0$.**

This is essentially just the first two terms of a [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) centered at $x_0$. You can do this whenever $f$ is locally analytic at $x_0$, to any number of terms that you wish (you can also technically do this for non-smooth functions, but with no guarantee that the series actually converges, so do so at your own risk).

As for why it works when $x$ is much smaller than $x_0$, even when $x$ is itself large: the first-term truncation of the Taylor series is considered to be accurate when $x_0-x\approx x_0$ (for functions that are locally analytic at $x_0$, the error on this approximation is given by Taylor's theorem). This is equivalent to saying that $x$ is much smaller than $x_0$. If it's not obvious to you why this is, consider rewriting $x_0-x$ as $x_0\left(1-\frac{x}{x_0}\right)$. If $x_0\left(1-\frac{x}{x_0}\right)\approx x_0$, then it follows that $1-\frac{x}{x_0}\approx 1$, meaning that $\frac{x}{x_0}\ll 1$.

As long as the radius of convergence of the Taylor series about $x_0$ is nonzero, there will always be **some** finite region around $x_0$ where the quadratic term is unimportant. This follows directly from the definition of differentiability.

The definition of the derivative is as follows:

$$f'(x_0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$$

In order for this limit to exist, there *must* be some value that the ratio on the right-hand side converges to. In other words, there must be some threshold $h_{max}$ such that, for all $h<h_{max}$, changing $h$ only varies the ratio within some tolerance $\epsilon$ (which you can make as small as you like; making $\epsilon$ smaller generally means $h_{max}$ will also get smaller). In the region where $h<h_{max}$, we have that $f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)\approx hf'(x_0)$, or in other words, that $f(x_0+h)\approx f(x_0)+f'(x_0)h$.

So we've shown that such a region must always exist, as long as the function is differentiable in the first place. But there are no guarantees made on the specific *width* of that region. Indeed, if the higher derivatives of $f$ are much larger than the first derivative, then the region in which this happens is very small. Essentially, the higher derivatives of the function determine *what the $\approx$ sign specifically means* when we say that $x_0-x\approx x_0$. Fortunately, you don't have to calculate the higher derivatives directly to obtain the width of this region; Taylor's theorem gives you an upper bound on the inaccuracy of your linear approximation, and the width of the region of validity is directly dependent on how much error you can accept.

Comment: How could one use the Taylor series approximations in the case of non-smooth functions? If the derivative does not exist, it doesn't seem possible to use the approximation. Additionally, the expansion you showed seems incorrect. The equation should read $f \left(x_0(1 - \frac{x}{x_0}) \right) = f(x_0) - f'(x_0)x_0\frac{x}{x_0}$.

Comment: @kb314 A function can be non-smooth and still be differentiable, twice-differentiable, etc. (since "smooth" usually means "differentiable infinitely many times"). Of course, if a higher-order derivative doesn't exist, you can't compute the full Taylor series centered at points where that happens, but it could still be the case that the approximation happens to be accurate anyway (for example, if the chosen center of your Taylor series has no non-differentiable points in its radius of convergence).

Comment: @kb314 It could also be the case that, even when you _do_ center a Taylor series on such a pathological point, the truncated Taylor series could be accurate enough for your purposes. It's just that the accuracy of the series is no longer guaranteed, and in particular the estimates of the error given by Taylor's theorem are invalid.

Comment: @kb314 On your second point, you are correct. Editing now.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @probably_someone. I always seem to need a refresher on the fact that smooth functions is the $C^\infty$ class!

Comment: @probably_someone +1 but tiny nitpick - smooth functions are not guaranteed to have convergent Taylor series, so the descriptor "locally analytic at $x_0$" would be more accurate.

Comment: @J.Murray, I hope the next comment has an *even* subtler point to make!

Comment: @J.Murray You're also correct. Editing.

Comment: Your rewritten equation seems have no effect on helping me understanding the question. Why just by writing x=x0*x/x0 you can say the approximation is accurate?

Comment: @YuanFang What specifically makes you think it isn't? Can you provide a specific example of when it wouldn't be?

Comment: @YuanFang You're right that the second part is a suboptimal explanation, though. Rewriting it now.

Comment: For example, when f''(x0)/2 is large, and x is also large, then in approximationg f(x-x0) you cannot ignore the quadratic term in the expansion because it may be much larger than the linear term.

Comment: @YuanFang Would it be easier to see if you were dealing with $f\left(1-\frac{x}{x_0}\right)$ instead of $f(x_0-x)$? In any physics situation, such a non-dimensionalization should always be possible (though not necessarily trivial).

Comment: If you consider $f(x)=g(x+10^{100})$ you can produce as many counterexamples to the statement as you want. Obviously it works only for some functions and in general case is wrong

Comment: @OON Counterexamples to which statement?

Comment: That you can use linear approximation if $x\ll x_0$

Comment: @OON Are you setting $x_0=10^{100}$? How does $f(x)$ relate to $f(x_0-x)$?

Comment: @OON Also, I don't see where I said it was correct in "the general case". I specifically stated that this was only guaranteed to work under conditions of local analyticity.

Comment: Wait no. It still does not work. Take $f(x)=\sin(x), x_0=10000\pi, x=2\pi$ local analiticity is ok

Answer (score 2):

The main difficulty you're running into is that there is no absolute sense in which a quantity with units can be considered "large," especially for the purposes of doing calculus. From the context, I would guess that you have three quantities with units that fit into this hierarchy: $E_0 \gg E \gg kT$, and $x_0 = E_0 / kT$ with $x = E/kT$.

For the purposes of approximating $f(x_0 - x) \approx f(x_0) - f'(x_0)x + \ldots$ the comparison that matters not $x$ to $x_0$. The important part comes from the [remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder) that says that the following relationship is exact:
$$f(x_0-x) = f(x_0) - f'(x_0)x + \frac{f''(\xi)}{2}x^2,$$
for some $0 < \xi < x$. Therefore, the thing you care about is whether you can show that quadratic term is smaller than the desired error (i.e. $x^2 f''(\xi)/2$ is small no matter where between 0 and $x$ $\xi$ is).

The fact that you're approximating $\ln\Omega$, though, means there's a good chance you're not actually using a Taylor series for $\Omega$, but an asymptotic series (specifically [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Stirling%27s_formula)). That adds additional wrinkles. That particular approximation doesn't want small arguments, it works better the larger its argument is, so $x_0 - x$ would also need to be large, requiring $x_0-x \gg 1$ and, with $x\gg 1$ that implies $x_0 \gg x$.